# VIM Question: When a .swp file exists, is it possible to add a "(D)elete" option

Tags: linux, vim

Many times when I lose connection to my development server, I just log back in and have a .swp file to deal with when I re-open. Does vim have a mod to allow deleting by initial prompt?

Thanks

Comment: According to usr_11.txt, line 217, Vim already supports this:

    WHAT TO DO?

    If dialogs are supported you will be asked to select one of five
    choices:

      Swap file ".main.c.swp" already exists! ~
      [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort, (D)elete it: ~
    <...>
    D  Delete the swap file. <...>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do have that option when a .swp file exists...

Swap file ".tjohej.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:

Perhaps a version thing? I've got.. VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jan 14 2010 06:43:50)
Included patches: 1-330

Answer (score 2):

I use the shortmess option to avoid the Attention Message.

set shortmess+=A